# Expand div from center of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question before wherein I wanted to [expand a div from the center of the body](http://Expand%20div%20from%20center%20of%20the%20body%20using%20jQuery). It works fine not until I encountered this scenario wherein the content of the body is long enough that a scroll bar now shows.

Notice on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adwb4q9x/3/) that when I scroll to a little to the bottom or just halfway then clicked anywhere on the page, the expanded div is displayed at the very top of the page.

I know this CSS code below has something to do with it:

```
.growme {
    background-color: #990000;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

How could I make the div expand right exactly at the view port regardless of where I scroll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change your position to fixed (which uses the viewport):

```
.growme {
    background-color: #990000;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w5w8orvp/

Comment: Didn't thought of that! Ha! Thanks a lot @Goowik

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
.growme {
    background-color: #990000;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;

    overflow:scroll;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/adwb4q9x/4/)

or

```
.growme {
    background-color: #990000;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;

}
p
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Here My Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/adwb4q9x/5/)

[DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/adwb4q9x/6/)

Comment: seems to have the same problem from here :)

Comment: the div still appears not centered (if i understood the question this is the problem)

Comment: ya i can understand wait sir @nowhere

Comment: Thanks for spending time to look into it @ivin raj though Goowik got the right answer. :)

Comment: Not sure why this is getting up-voted, neither of the suggestions fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry sir @HiddenHobbes